# Why does Google cripple the 2FA Google Authenticator PAM module?

Tags: passwords, authentication, compliance, multi-factor, google

If you enable 2FA for Google Apps the shared secret is 160 bits. The `google_authenticator` PAM module on the other hand seems to use 80 bits for the shared secret.

According to [RFC 4226](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4226.txt):

> R6 - The algorithm MUST use a strong shared secret.  The length of
>   the shared secret MUST be at least 128 bits. This document
>   RECOMMENDs a shared secret length of 160 bits.

Note "MUST" not "SHOULD". So that makes Google Authenticator non compliant.

What's the rationale behind doing this?

Comment: Great question! I opened an issue on the google-authenticator project page about this. https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/issues/detail?id=340&can=4

Comment: I can only speculate that someone judged it good enough as a tradeoff to get the benefit of fitting the secret inside a smaller QR code. Of course that doesn't answer the question why one would risk potentially sacrificing security for convenience.

Comment: I tried to get in touch with Google's sec team about this a few years ago when we were looking at OTP implementations and received a 'by design' response. I wouldn't mind so much but the Wikipedia page seems to perpetually claim compliance with RFC 4226 and/or 6238, when this is simply not true.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [initial commit](https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/source/detail?r=35ae38faf1a7a55b8d1808d893d2e4c4a1ef7824&path=/libpam/google-authenticator.c) for this code already includes the "80 bits" secret key length. It was not changed afterwards.

Now let's analyze things more critically. HOTP is specified in [RFC 4226](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4226). Authentication uses a "shared secret", which is the value that we are talking about. What does RFC 4226 says about it ? Essentially, there is a a *requirement* in [section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4226#section-4):

> ```
> R6 - The algorithm MUST use a strong shared secret.  The length of
> ```

```
the shared secret MUST be at least 128 bits.  This document
RECOMMENDs a shared secret length of 160 bits.
```

And then [section 7.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4226#section-7.5) explains at length various methods for generating the shared secret.

Now the `google_authenticator` code generates an 80-bit shared secret with `/dev/urandom` and then proceeds to *encode* this secret with [Base32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32): this encoding maps each group of 5 bits to a printable character. The resulting string thus consists of 16 characters, which are written "as is" in a file, with ASCII encoding, meaning that *in the file* the shared secret has length... 16 *bytes*, i.e. 128 bits. It is thus *possible* that the initial confusion comes from that: what is stored has a length which can be seen, in a way, to comply with requirement R6 of RFC 4226.

Of course, the RFC talks about the "shared secret" by calling it "*K*" in [section 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4226#section-5.1) and then proceeds to using it as key for HMAC ([section 5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4226#section-5.3), step 1). With the shared secret generated with the command-line tool in `google_authenticator`, what enters HMAC really is a sequence of 80 bits, not 128 bits, even though these 80 bits happen to be *encoded* as 128 bits when stored (but they are decoded back to 80 bits upon usage). Thus, this 80-bit secret cannot really, in a legalistic way, comply with requirement R6 of RFC 4226. However, the confusion on "length" (after or before encoding) may explain this feature of `google_authenticator`.

Note, though, that this is just for the command-line tool which can be used to generate the secret as an initial step. The rest of the code supports longer secret values.

(Another theory is that the author wanted to test his code, and, in particular, test the situation in which there is no QR code. In that case, the user must *type* the code, and an 80-bit secret is easier to type than a 128-bit or 160-bit secret. Possibly, the author first used a short secret to ease development, and subsequently forgot to set it back to its nominal length afterwards. This sort of mishap happens quite often.)

---

**Is it critical ?** With my cryptographer's hat, I must answer: no. An 80-bit secret key is still quite strong against brute force, because even with a lot of GPU, *2<sup>79</sup>* evaluations of HMAC/SHA-1 will still take quite some time (with an 80-bit key, average cost of brute force is that of trying half the possible keys, i.e. *2<sup>79</sup>* evaluations). Indeed, HMAC/SHA-1 is deemed "cryptographically strong", meaning that the best known attack is brute force on the key. Let's put figures on it:

HMAC/SHA-1 uses two SHA-1 invocation. So the attack cost is, on average, the cost involved by calling SHA-1 *2<sup>80</sup>* times. [This page](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/) shows benchmarks at 2.5 billions of SHA-1 calls per second for a good GPU. If you are mounting a cracking farm, you will usually use a "middle range" GPU, not a top-notch model, because you will get more power-per-dollar that way. Let's assume that you use 100$ GPU that can do *2<sup>31</sup>* SHA-1 per second (that's a bit more than 2 billions). With a budget of *one billion dollars* you can have ten millions of such GPU, and they will run the attack in an average of... 652 days.

Of course, 10 millions of GPU take quite some room and, more importantly, use a substantial amount of power. If we suppose that each GPU can run in 50W (a quite optimistic figure), then each attack run will need a bit less than 8 TW.h (terawatt-hours). I live in Canada, province of Québec, where electricity is known to be very cheap due to huge dams and substantial government subventions, resulting in a price of about 0.05$ per kW.h (see [the prices](http://www.hydroquebec.com/residential/understanding-your-bill/rates/residential-rates/)). With this price, each attack run will cost around *400 millions of dollars* on electricity alone. This does not include cooling prices, because all this energy will become heat and will have to be dissipated (to some extent, a Canadian winter can help). Also, notice that all the GPU will collectively draw 500 MW, a non-discreet amount (that's about half of a nuclear power plant...).

What this amounts to is the following: **in practice, an 80-bit key is strong enough**. I would be nervous if an 80-bit key protected the launch code for nuclear missiles; however, if the strategic dissuasion was protected by Google's 2FA, I would also be quite nervous for... other reasons.

So we can say that while this 80-bit secret is non-compliant and academically "a bit short", it still is quite strong and does not mandate immediate and drastic actions. It would be cool if the code was fixed; the World won't stop spinning if it is not.

Comment: It's not just HMAC/SHA-1, but a modulo 10^6 of the actual hash. The attack scenario for a HOTP token generating 6-digit codes is an attacker using previously known codes to arrive at the shared secret, which, considering this truncation, makes the attacker's job even more difficult due to increased chance of collisions.

Comment: "*The rest of the code supports longer secret values.*" To be explicit: there is no such limit in the PAM *module* itself, it will accept any (> 1 byte, and subject to a sanity-check maximum file size of 64kiB) shared secret size. It is only the local secret generation tool that has this (trivially modifiable) limit. FWIW, the most recent source (v2.21) for the Android app has a *lower* limit of 80 bits (`MIN_KEY_BYTES`).

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this in the present year, it appears this was resolved back in 2016 https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam/commit/fb9a769ab11cf1cac0d06af41b73bfbd5fcfb0af

Answer (score 10):

Like I mentioned in my comment, I have already opened an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/issues/detail?id=340&sort=-id) on the Google Authenticator repository. However, there has been no official replies from the developers on it. It appears that the activity on the repository is pretty stagnant.

While there is probably no good explanation for why Google opted for 80 bits instead of the recommended 160 bits as per the RFC, there is a pretty easy fix if this is an important issue.

As far as I can tell, the size of the secret is solely defined in `libpam/google-authenticator.c` on line 39.

```
#define SECRET_BITS               80          // Must be divisible by eight
```

Changing the value from 80 to 160 works and breaks nothing as far as I can tell. This might be viable if you really want the PAM module to be compliant with the RFC.

Comment: adnan, you are being too harsh here. As your question currently stands, it can only be answered by the Google employee that was involved with this. As for the bounty... 50 rep is not going to please any repwhore....

Comment: @Lekensteyn Rules are rules. Just because Terry is our friend and we like him, it doesn't mean we look the other way when he provides a non-answer as an answer. If the question can only be answer by a Google employee, then it's probably not best asked here and should be closed not non-answer answered.